# Render Razor View outside the MVC 6 context

Tags: razor, asp.net-core-mvc, portable-class-library

I'm working on a Class Library (Package) which should be able to render an embedded Razor View to a string. I'm using '"Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final"' package.

Is there any way to render a view to string without using ActionContext/HttpContext and not using "http://antaris.github.io/RazorEngine/"?

Comment: Decided to use MVC 6 ViewComponent instead. I was not able to make RazorEngine working with DNX.